# Are built-in intrinsic functions available in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, optimization, intrinsics, built-in

I can see various built-in functions (like __builtin_popount, __builtin_clz, etc) in the Xcode auto-completion pop-up. I'm not sure where these are getting picked up from though. Command clicking doesn't lead to a swift definition or any documentation. Are any __builtin_* or equivalent intrinsic functions available in Swift 3 and if so, what modules do I need to include and how can I call them?

Comment: I believe they are referenced within LLVM/clang