# Find most significant bit in Swift

Tags: swift, bit-manipulation

I need to find the value (or position) of the [most significant bit (MSB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) of an integer in Swift.

Eg:

- **Input number:** 9
- **Input as binary:** 1001
- **MS *value* as binary:** 1000 -> (which is 8 in decimal)
- **MS *position* as decimal:** 3 (because `1<<3 == 1000`)

Many processors (Intel, AMD, ARM) have instructions for this. In c, [these are exposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673781/2547229). Are these instructions similarly available in Swift through a library function, or would I need to [implement some bit twiddling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/671905/2547229)?

The value is more useful in my case.

If a position is returned, then the value can be easily derived by a single shift.

Conversely, computing position from value is not so easy unless a fast [Hamming Weight / pop count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) function is available.

Comment: The value is easier to find with bit manipulation (like the thing you linked minus the magic DeBruijn multiply/lookup) but I don't know enough about Swift to say anything about built-ins other than that I couldn't find one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `flsl()` function ("find last set bit, long"):

```
let x = 9
let p = flsl(x)
print(p) // 4
```

The result is `4` because `flsl()` and the related functions number the bits starting at 1, the least significant bit.

On Intel platforms you can use the `_bit_scan_reverse` intrinsic,
in my test in a macOS application this translated to a `BSR`
instruction.

```
import _Builtin_intrinsics.intel

let x: Int32 = 9
let p = _bit_scan_reverse(x)
print(p) // 3
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks – do you know if this compiles to an assembly instruction on intel / ARM?

Comment: It's worth command clicking that function name and seeing its sibling methods in the library header. Methods are available for the least significant bit also, and variants for `Int32`, `Int64` and just the machine's native word sized `Int` (although the naming seems irregular).

Comment: @Benjohn: It seems that it compiles to a library call. On Intel platforms there is also `_bit_scan_reverse()` (which *is* an intrinsic), you can make it available e.g. with `import simd` . I haven't found an equivalent for ARM yet.

Comment: @Benjohn: Re naming: The `l` suffix is for functions taking a `long`, and that happens to be what `Int` is in Swift (32 or 64 bit).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353482/are-built-in-intrinsic-functions-available-in-swift-3. For some reason, `__builtin_clz` compiles, but gives a linker error.

Comment: Of slightly obscure interest, I discovered that to _compare_ the most significant bit of two integers, there is an amazingly neat bit twiddle you can do. So, the result of `lfsl(a) < lfsl(b)` is equal to `(a < b) && (a < a^b)`, which basically blew my mind with its elegance – and is by good fortune what I actually need to compute. The algorithm is mentioned on the wikipedia page for the [z-order curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the the properties `leadingZeroBitCount` and `trailingZeroBitCount` to find the Most Significant Bit and Least Significant Bit.

For example,

```
let i: Int = 95

let lsb = i.trailingZeroBitCount
let msb = Int.bitWidth - 1 - i.leadingZeroBitCount

print("i: \(i) = \(String(i, radix: 2))") // i: 95 = 1011111
print("lsb: \(lsb) = \(String(1 << lsb, radix: 2))") // lsb: 0 = 1
print("msb: \(msb) = \(String(1 << msb, radix: 2))") // msb: 6 = 1000000
```

If you look at the disassembly(ARM Mac) in LLDB for the Least Significant Bit code, it uses a single instruction, `clz`, to count the zeroed bits. ([ARM Reference](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0802/a/A64-General-Instructions/CLZ))

```
** 15       let lsb = i.trailingZeroBitCount

    0x100ed947c <+188>:  rbit   x9, x8
    0x100ed9480 <+192>:  clz    x9, x9
    0x100ed9484 <+196>:  mov    x10, x9
    0x100ed9488 <+200>:  str    x10, [sp, #0x2d8]
```